# Apache URL Rewrite On the same Virtual Host works in one case but fails in another

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, rewrite

I have an odd problem, where I am rewriting a URL to proxy to two different URL destinations, based on digits that are passed in the URL and a particular string, in the same virtualhost definition, which works perfectly in one case, but  does not in the other. The VHost definition also includes a proxypass definition. I just cannot get the second URL to be presented to the user. 
The server VHOST configuration is like so:

```
    Listen 9443
    NameVirtualHost *:9443
    <VirtualHost *:9443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT
    RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 9
    SSLProxyEngine On
    RewriteEngine On

    #Condition One, match digits 100-9999 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:a-http-header-message} ^(\b[1-9][0-9]{2,3}\b)$
    #do not honor if sessionId is found
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !sessionId= [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/standup/main/menu.xml(.*)$ https://someexternal.com/shiv/010$1 [P]

    #Condition Two, Match digits 0-99
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:a-http-header-message} ^(\b[0-9]{1,2}\b)
    #do not honor if sessionId is found
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !sessionId=
    RewriteRule ^/standup/main/menu.xml(.*)$ https://localhost.localdomain:9443/response.xml$1 [P]


    ProxyPass /standup http://localhost:99999/standup
    ProxyPassReverse /standup http://localhost:99999/standup

    </VirtualHost>
```

The issue is, when Condition Two is called, instead of what is at https://localhost.localdomain:9443/response.xml to be presented, the user sees only what is at http://localhost:99999/standup/

This does not affect Condition One at all. The response.xml is reachable from the server easily, both internally and externally.
Also I have the exact same setup on a different server and it works great there! SELinux is disabled, too.
 Please can someone help me see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. What is in the rewrite log?

Comment: 2. Have you checked that the config files on this server and the one where it works actually are the same? Copy them both to one machine and run a diff on them.

Comment: Is a dollar sign ($) missing at the end of "RewriteCond" under Condition 2? I'm just looking at the differences between the 2, and see that as a possibility...

Comment: Oh my goodness a typo...in the actual config file. I feel so dumb. Condition One: RewriteCond %{HTTP:whoisd-ussd-message} and Condition Two: RewriteCond %{HTTP:whosid-ussd-message}

Comment: Thank you Jen for making me take a hard look at the file for the hundredth time.